# Issue in Web Content Viewer Portlet in websphere portal 8

Tags: websphere-portal

What I did:

1. I have created one Authoring Template with one Rich Text, one Presentation Template, one Site Area and one Content Item and then I added these contents on one page (say TestPage1) by using Web Content Viewer Portlet.
2. Now I have to do same things as step 1, but here the Content Item is a simple Text Field.

I added these contents on another page (say TestPage2) by using Web Content Viewer portlet.

But the problem is that the contents of TestPage1 (RichText on TestPage1) is completely replaced by contents of TestPage2, which means when I added web content viewer portlet on any page and if I configure it then this new configuration setting is updated on every previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I added web content viewer portlet on any page and if I configure it then this new configuration setting is updated on every previous page

I suppose you tried change Web Content Viewr portlet settings in Configure mode. You should do it in Edit Shared Settings mode

- **Configure** - applies settings to all portlet instances.
- **Edit Share Settings** - applies settings to one portlet instance.